# How to populate a list inside a collection in JSON format in Windows PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

I'm working on a task, where-in I should invoke a REST Post request in Powershell environment.

Based on google research, I decided to use `Invoke-RestMethod` cmdlet.
For the `POST` request, the body should be in JSON format as below.

```
{
  "appid": "sample string 1",
  "appName": "sample string 2",
  "appType": "sample string 3",
  "hostName": "sample string 4",
  "userName": "sample string 5",
  "password": "sample string 6",
  "status": "sample string 7",
  "appUri": "sample string 8",
  "resourceParams": [
    {
      "data1": "sample string 1",
      "data2": "sample string 2",
      "data3": "sample string 3"
    },
    {
      "data1": "sample string 1",
      "data2": "sample string 2",
      "data3": "sample string 3"
    }
  ],
  "Params": [
    {
      "hostName": "sample string 1",
      "ip": "sample string 2"
    },
    {
      "hostName": "sample string 1",
      "ip": "sample string 2"
    },
    {
      "hostName": "sample string 1",
      "ip": "sample string 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now inorder to populate this json content, I used the code like below

```
$externalAPP = @{
    appId =  1
    appName =  "test"
    appType = 1
    userName = "Administrator@test"
    password = "xxxxxxxx"
    status = "1"
    resourceParams = @{
        data1 = "test"
        data2 = "test"
        data3 = "test"
    }
    Params = {@{
        hostName =  "ex1"
        ipAddress = "192.1.1.1"
    }
    @{
        hostName =  "ex2"
        ipAddress =  "192.1.1.2"
    }
    }


}

$json = $externalAPP | ConvertTo-Json

Write-Host $json
```

Above code works fine, if there is only one item in `resourceParams` & `Params`. If there is more than one, the format is something different as follows.

**Sample Ouptut**

```
    "appName":  "test",
    "esxiParams":  {
                       "Attributes":  [

                                      ],
                       "File":  "C:\\Users\\kspviswa\\Desktop\\Demo3\\test.ps1",
                       "IsFilter":  false,
                       "IsConfiguration":  false,
                       "Module":  null,
                       "StartPosition":  {
                                             "Content":  "{@{\r\n\t\thostName =  \"ex1\"\r\n\t\tipAddress = \"192.
"\r\n\t}\r\n\t@{\r\n\t\thostName =  \"ex2\"\r\n\t\tipAddress =  \"192.1.1.2\"\r\n\t}\r\n\t}",
                                             "Type":  19,
                                             "Start":  292,
                                             "Length":  117,
                                             "StartLine":  14,
                                             "StartColumn":  15,
                                             "EndLine":  22,
                                             "EndColumn":  3
                                         },
                       "DebuggerHidden":  false,
                       "Ast":  {
                                   "ParamBlock":  null,
                                   "BeginBlock":  null,
                                   "ProcessBlock":  null,
                                   "EndBlock":  "@{\r\n\t\thostName =  \"ex1\"\r\n\t\tipAddress = \"192.1.1.1\"\r\
\n\t@{\r\n\t\thostName =  \"ex2\"\r\n\t\tipAddress =  \"192.1.1.2\"\r\n\t}",
                                   "DynamicParamBlock":  null,
                                   "ScriptRequirements":  null,
                                   "Extent":  "{@{\r\n\t\thostName =  \"ex1\"\r\n\t\tipAddress = \"192.1.1.1\"\r\n
n\t@{\r\n\t\thostName =  \"ex2\"\r\n\t\tipAddress =  \"192.1.1.2\"\r\n\t}\r\n\t}",
                                   "Parent":  "{@{\r\n\t\thostName =  \"ex1\"\r\n\t\tipAddress = \"192.1.1.1\"\r\n
n\t@{\r\n\t\thostName =  \"ex2\"\r\n\t\tipAddress =  \"192.1.1.2\"\r\n\t}\r\n\t}"
                               }
                   },
    "password":  "xxxx"
}
```

What is the mistake I have done? I had tried several websites seeking for the answer. All the examples were for flattened container. I want to understand, how to populate list inside a container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSON, `[]` means *list* or *array* - so instead of enclosing the `Params` value in `{}` (which makes it a scriptblock), use the array subexpression operator `@()` instead:

```
$externalAPP = @{
  appId =  1
  appName =  "test"
  appType = 1
  userName = "Administrator@test"
  password = "xxxxxxxx"
  status = "1"
  resourceParams = @(
    @{
      data1 = "test"
      data2 = "test"
      data3 = "test"
    }
  )
  Params = @(
    @{
      hostName =  "ex1"
      ipAddress = "192.1.1.1"
    },
    @{
      hostName =  "ex2"
      ipAddress =  "192.1.1.2"
    }
  )
}
```

Which will produce:

```
{
    "userName":  "Administrator@test",
    "appType":  1,
    "appId":  1,
    "Params":  [
                   {
                       "ipAddress":  "192.1.1.1",
                       "hostName":  "ex1"
                   },
                   {
                       "ipAddress":  "192.1.1.2",
                       "hostName":  "ex2"
                   }
               ],
    "resourceParams":  [
                           {
                               "data1":  "test",
                               "data2":  "test",
                               "data3":  "test"
                           }
                       ],
    "status":  "1",
    "appName":  "test",
    "password":  "xxxxxxxx"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I know it should be a basic mistake. however couldn't get through this since I'm a newbie in powershell.